# How to run codes line by line in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm new in node.js. I know it uses asynchronous programming but I need to write a loop for asking user to input some data and then after user inputs data, ask again and again till the loop ends. 
I tried this code but the output is like this:
Insert Data?
Insert Data?
Insert Data?
and when I wanna input something it's like: aaallliii

```
for (index=1;index<=3;index++){
    console.log("Insert Data?");
    prompt.start();
    prompt.get(['data'], function (err, result) 
    {
    });
    }
```

how can I write the code to use it like normal loops?

Comment: `I know it uses asynchronous programming` only the asynchronous parts are asynchronous, the synchronous parts are ... drum roll ... syncrhonous ... what is `prompt` in your code?

Comment: @JaromandaX I run code in command line, prompt helps me to ask user for data i think. I found it in stackoverflow.

Comment: Look into using `async/await` for the easiest solution, otherwise look into Promises and resolving them in series.

Comment: but none of this code **needs** anything asynchronous - so if `prompt` is in some way asynchronous, then it's the wrong tool - a link to what `prompt` is would help

Comment: If you're using node... chances are you're going to need something asynchronous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `async/await`, if you are able to use node v7.6.

`async/await` lets you use asynchronous stuff and write the code in a way that looks more synchronous. In your case, you want to prompt the user for input, then *await* their response before continuing. The `await` keyword lets you write the code in the same way, "blocking" until the user has given input (although everything is still asynchronous, it's just syntactic sugar basically)

```
async function insertData() {
    for (let index = 1; index <= 3; index++) {
        console.log("Insert Data?");
        prompt.start();
        let input = await new Promise(resolve => {
            prompt.get(['data'], (err, result) => {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
        // do something with input
    }
}

insertData().then(() => console.log("Done prompting."));
```

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what i wanted.